# Combining results from two Either Monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How do you handle this situation (pseudocode provided below) in Haskell?

```
 x = somethingThatReturnsMaybe(s1)
 y = somethingThatReturnsMaybe(s2)

 if(x == Nothing) return Left "invalid x"
 if(y == Nothing) return Left "invalid y"

 callFn(fromJust(x), fromJust(y));
```

I can think of two ways:-

1. Pass Maybes from calling place, so that the above code can be wrapped in a function, and I can use pattern matching in the function binding/definition.
2. I have written this code to combine these values using Either

```
mapToRight (\(x, y) -> callFn x y) combined_values
                where { combined_values = (maybeToRight "Invalid x!" x >>= combiner) <*>
                                        maybeToRight "Invalid target position" y;
                mapToRight = second; x = somethingThatReturnsMaybe s1; y = somethingThatReturnsMaybe s2
                }
```

For the second option I have following combinators

```
combiner :: b -> Either a (b0 -> (b, b0));
combiner x = Right (x,)

maybeToRight :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
maybeToRight a Nothing = Left a
maybeToRight a (Just x) = Right x
```

Is there any preference among these two (although the first one is less preferable to me because it might involve more changes), or is there any better option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would import [`Control.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Control-Error.html), then write this:

```
do
    x <- note "invalid x" (somethingThatReturnsMaybe s1)
    y <- note "invalid y" (somethingThatReturnsMaybe s2)
    callFn x y
```

The [`note`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:note) here is your `maybeToRight`. The `Either`'s implementation of `(>>=)` is handling the unwrapping/combining.

Comment: +1, I didn't know about `note`. Given that it's literally `note a = maybe (Left a) Right`, one might question if it's so close to the [Fairbairn threshold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fairbairn_threshold) that it'd be easier just to use `maybe` instead of importing `Control.Error`...

Comment: I always think of "Fairbairn threshold" but didn't know it had a name.